# Cleanly arranging checklist items dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I work on a dashboard using plotly dash and need to display a checklist with about 60 options. However, the number is not fixed so arranging of the options has to be done dynamically. I am using:

```
dcc.Checklist(
   id="checklist",
   options=possible_fields,
   value=[],
   inline=True,
)
```

Unfortunately the option labels are not always of the same length which leads to an unclean appearance:

```
 ab  acd  ad
 a  abcd  ae
 abc  acdc  af
```

How can I dynamically arrange the options cleanly? e.g.

```
 ab   acd   ad
 a    abcd  ae
 abc  acdc  af
```

Comment: Process the `possible_fields` first, use `str.rjust` to add spaces to the string. [Check this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-padding-to-a-string-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

```
possible_fields = ['a', 'aaa', 'aam', 'aaaaa']

lengths = [len(s) for s in possible_fields]
largest_length = max(lengths)

possible_fields = [ s.ljust(largest_length, " ") for s in possible_fields ]
```

Something like this should leave your `possible_fields` array with strings that all have the same amount of characters, padded with spaces on the right.

This won't produce the output you expect:

```
 ab   acd   ad
 a    abcd  ae
 abc  acdc  af
```

It will probably produce something like this (notice the spaces on the first column)

```
 ab    acd   ad
 a     abcd  ae
 abc   acdc  af
```

But I'm just assuming since I don't know what `dcc.Checklist` does.

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks. Did not see the forest for the trees.

Comment: @SimonP. Just updated to point out that the first column probably won't look exactly as you expect.

Comment: FYI Making each entry the same number of characters will only align properly when using a monospaced font.